# Ratio of matching rows per group

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I'd like to calculate the ratio of items in a group that fulfil certain criteria out of the total number of items in that group. I've already solved this but am curious to know if my solution is optimal, as the query takes a problematically long time over my large (10m+) dataset.

Here is what I have in its simplest form:

```
create table #tableA 
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    groupid int,
    flag bit,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )
)

insert into #tableA (groupid,flag) values (1,0),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1)

select 
    a.groupid ,
    cast(totalCount as float)/count(*) as ratio
from 
    #tableA a 
    join 
    (
        select 
            groupid,
            COUNT(*) totalCount 
        from 
            #tableA 
        where 
            flag=1 
        group by 
            groupid
    ) b on a.groupid=b.groupid 
group by 
    a.groupid,
    b.totalCount

drop table #tableA
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `flag` is 0 or 1, this should work:

```
select groupid ,
       cast(sum(flag) as float)/count(*) as ratio
from tableA
group by groupid
```

If `flag` can take other values, a `CASE` or `IF()` should help make `SUM` work anyway.

Comment: I'm still testing and may need to append to the question before closing

Comment: If [flag] is really a bit then you'll need to cast it to something larger before you SUM it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, you're right, TSQL (differing from mysql here) does say "except for the bit data type" in the docs for SUM, so it will need a cast (or CASE or IF as I mentioned for more general cases in the answer).

Answer (score 4):

select groupid ,
       AVG(cast(flag as float)) as ratio
from tableA
group by groupid

Comment: Really, flag is a null or non-null match from a joined column, so combined with a case statement giving 0 for null and 1 for non-null (from Alex Martelli's answer), this makes for a elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: I agree, this is certainly a very elegant solution! Worked well for me too! Thanks